# Injecting function call after __init__ with decorator

Tags: python, pyqt4, decorator

I'm trying to find the best way to create a class decorator that does the following:

1. Injects a few functions into the decorated class
2. Forces a call to one of these functions AFTER the decorated class' `__init__` is called

Currently, I'm just saving off a reference to the 'original' `__init__` method and replacing it with my `__init__` that calls the original and my additional function.  It looks similar to this:

```
orig_init = cls.__init__

def new_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    'Extend' wrapped class' __init__ so we can attach to all signals
    automatically
    """

    orig_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self._debugSignals()

cls.__init__ = new_init
```

Is there a better way to 'augment' the original `__init__` or inject my call somewhere else?  All I really need is for my `self._debugSignals()` to be called sometime after the object is created.  I also want it happen automatically, which is why I thought after `__init__` was a good place.

### Extra misc. decorator notes

It might be worth mentioning some background on this decorator.  You can find the full code [here](https://gist.github.com/durden/5367247).  The point of the decorator is to automatically attach to any PyQt signals and print when they are emitted.  The decorator works fine when I decorate my own subclasses of `QtCore.QObject`, however I've been recently trying to [automatically decorate all QObject children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959232/dynamically-add-a-decorator-to-class).

I'd like to have a 'debug' mode in the application where I can automatically print ALL signals just to make sure things are doing what I expect.  I'm sure this will result in TONS of debug, but I'd still like to see what's happening.

The problem is my current version of the decorator is causing a [segfault when replacing `QtCore.QObject.__init__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959232/dynamically-add-a-decorator-to-class#comment22745728_15959264).  I've tried to debug this, but the code is all SIP generated, which I don't have much experience with.

So, I was wondering if there was a safer, more pythonic way to inject a function call AFTER the `__init__` and hopefully avoid the segfault.

Comment: Not a solution, but some info: `QtCore.QObject.__init__` is implemented inside the Qt library, ie. in C++, which is why you can't simply replace `__init__`.

Comment: @rainer That makes sense.  I tried to look at the `QtCore.QObject.__init__` source but I got lost in all the sip/C++ magic that creates the wrappers, etc.  This explains why my decorator works on python-based objects (or at least ones that don't wrap so closely with the sip/c++ layer).  However, I was thinking maybe there is a cleaner way to achieve this behavior without hijacking `__init__` because I don't really like this behavior for python-based objects either.  However, 'it just works' for the python objects.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on [this post](http://martyalchin.com/2008/jan/10/simple-plugin-framework/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510286/plugin-architecture-plugin-manager-vs-inspecting-from-plugins-import/17401329#17401329), an alternative way to do this is through a custom [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python). This would work as follows (tested in Python 2.7):

```
# define a new metaclass which overrides the "__call__" function
class NewInitCaller(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """Called when you call MyNewClass() """
        obj = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        obj.new_init()
        return obj


# then create a new class with the __metaclass__ set as our custom metaclass
class MyNewClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = NewInitCaller
    def __init__(self):
        print "Init class"
    def new_init(self):
        print "New init!!"

# when you create an instance
a = MyNewClass()
>>> Init class
>>> New init!!
```

The basic idea is that:

1. when you call `MyNewClass()` it searches for the metaclass, finds that you have defined `NewInitCaller`
2. The metaclass  `__call__` function is called.
3. This function creates the `MyNewClass` instance using `type`,
4. The instance runs its own `__init__` (printing "Init class").
5. The meta class then calls the `new_init` function of the instance.

Comment: This won't work for my specific scenario with PyQt and the QtCore.QObject.  This is because the object I'm trying to monkey-patch is implemented in C, not pure Python.  However, this solution will work quite well for a pure Python object.

Comment: Ahh... thats a pain.  As a side note, your decorator doesn't appear to return `cls` at the end.  I'm assuming you've just posted an extract?

Comment: Yes, just posted a snippet.  The real decorator should return `cls`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a generalized form of jake77's example which implements `__post_init__` on a non-dataclass. This enables a subclass's `configure()` to be automatically invoked in correct sequence after the base & subclass `__init__`s have completed.

```
# define a new metaclass which overrides the "__call__" function
class PostInitCaller(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """Called when you call BaseClass() """
        print(f"{__class__.__name__}.__call__({args}, {kwargs})")
        obj = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        obj.__post_init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj


# then create a new class with the metaclass passed as an argument
class BaseClass(object, metaclass=PostInitCaller):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"{__class__.__name__}.__init__({args}, {kwargs})")
        super().__init__()

    def __post_init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"{__class__.__name__}.__post_init__({args}, {kwargs})")
        self.configure(*args, **kwargs)

    def configure(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"{__class__.__name__}.configure({args}, {kwargs})")


class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"{__class__.__name__}.__init__({args}, {kwargs})")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def configure(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"{__class__.__name__}.configure({args}, {kwargs})")
        super().configure(*args, **kwargs)

# when you create an instance
a = SubClass('a', b='b')
```

running gives:

```
PostInitCaller.__call__(('a',), {'b': 'b'})
SubClass.__init__(('a',), {'b': 'b'})
BaseClass.__init__(('a',), {'b': 'b'})
BaseClass.__post_init__(('a',), {'b': 'b'})
SubClass.configure(('a',), {'b': 'b'})
BaseClass.configure(('a',), {'b': 'b'})
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution for Python 3.x, based on [this post's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013249/metaclass-in-python3-5). Also see [PEP 3115](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/) for reference, I think the rationale is an interesting read.

Changes in the example above are shown with comments; the only real change is the way the metaclass is defined, all other are trivial 2to3 modifications.

```
# define a new metaclass which overrides the "__call__" function
class NewInitCaller(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """Called when you call MyNewClass() """
        obj = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        obj.new_init()
        return obj

# then create a new class with the metaclass passed as an argument
class MyNewClass(object, metaclass=NewInitCaller):  # added argument
    # __metaclass__ = NewInitCaller  this line is removed; would not have effect
    def __init__(self):
        print("Init class")  # function, not command
    def new_init(self):
        print("New init!!")  # function, not command

# when you create an instance
a = MyNewClass()
>>> Init class
>>> New init!!
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that the **metaclass** approach is the Pro way, but I've a more readable and easy proposal using @staticmethod:

```
class Invites(TimestampModel, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    invitee_email = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    
    def __init__(self, invitee_email):
        invitee_email = invitee_email

    @staticmethod
    def create_invitation(invitee_email):
        """
        Create an invitation
        saves it and fetches it because the id
        is being generated in the DB
        """
        invitation = Invites(invitee_email)
        db.session.save(invitation)
        db.session.commit()

        return Invites.query.filter(
            PartnerInvites.invitee_email == invitee_email
        ).one_or_none()
```

So I could use it this way:

```
invitation = Invites.create_invitation("jim@mail.com")
print(invitation.id, invitation.invitee_email)

>>>> 1 jim@mail.com
```