# __metaclass__ in Python 3

Tags: python, metaclass

In Python2.7 this code can work very well, `__getattr__` in `MetaTable` 
will run. But in Python 3 it doesn't work.

```
class MetaTable(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, key):
        temp = key.split("__")
        name = temp[0]
        alias = None

        if len(temp) > 1:
            alias = temp[1]

        return cls(name, alias)


class Table(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaTable

    def __init__(self, name, alias=None):
        self._name = name
        self._alias = alias


d = Table
d.student__s
```

But in Python 3.5 I get an attribute error instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wyx/project/python3/sql/dd.py", line 31, in <module>
    d.student__s
AttributeError: type object 'Table' has no attribute 'student__s'
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Python 3 [changed how you specify a metaclass](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/), `__metaclass__` is no longer checked.

Use `metaclass=...` in the class *signature*:

```
class Table(object, metaclass=MetaTable):
```

Demo:

```
>>> class MetaTable(type):
...     def __getattr__(cls, key):
...         temp = key.split("__")
...         name = temp[0]
...         alias = None
...         if len(temp) > 1:
...             alias = temp[1]
...         return cls(name, alias)
...
>>> class Table(object, metaclass=MetaTable):
...     def __init__(self, name, alias=None):
...         self._name = name
...         self._alias = alias
...
>>> d = Table
>>> d.student__s
<__main__.Table object at 0x10d7b56a0>
```

If you need to provide support for both Python 2 and 3 in your codebase, you can use the [`six.with_metaclass()` baseclass generator](https://six.readthedocs.io/#six.with_metaclass) or the [`@six.add_metaclass()` class decorator](https://six.readthedocs.io/#six.add_metaclass) to specify the metaclass.

Comment: Thanks for this. It got my favourite plugin system working in python 3.

Comment: ```It would be possible to leave the existing __metaclass__ syntax in place```. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/

Comment: @CodeFarmer: yes, but it doesn't do anything any more.