# Python contextmanager and object creation

Tags: python, callback, contextmanager

I would like to create a contextmanager that would intercept any object instantiation from a given class or subclasses of this classes and do something with the object.

I sudo code it could look like something like this:

```
with my_context_watchdog(my_callback, BaseClass):
     obj_1 = BaseClass(name) # launch callback
     obj_2 = SubClass(name) # launch callback

     obj_3 = RandomClass(name) # does not launch callback

def my_callback(new_obj):
     print("new object name:", new_obj.name)
```

Is there anyway I could do something like this in Python?

The best would be that the callback is executed only **after** the object has been fully instantiated.

**Important:** I can't modify any of the object classes, they are in a library I don't have any control on it. I just want to raise a callback when some of the Classes of this library are instantiated.

Maybe the contextmanager is not the best idea, I'm opened to any other solution.

Answer (score 2):

The context manager doesn't actually see code in the `with` block. If you see a library doing something "magical" like this, there is usually a hidden global variable somewhere in the background, and the functions called inside the `with` block actively cooperate with the context manager.

That said, there's two options for you. One makes sense and one is very ugly.

The one that makes sense:

```
# somewhere in the context manager:
class ContextManagerReturnVal:
    def instantiate(self, cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        if issubclass(cls, self.base_class):
            self.callback(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return obj

with watchdog(callback, BaseClass) as instantiate:
    obj1 = instantiate(BaseClass, name)
    obj2 = instantiate(SubClass, name)
```

And the ugly one is monkey-patching the `BaseClass`. You said in a comment that you can't *modify* the `BaseClass` - depends on what exactly you mean by that. If you can't modify the source code, you could still modify the class at run-time, like here: [Monkey patching a class in another module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545982/monkey-patching-a-class-in-another-module-in-python)
You would have to store the original `__init__` method and return it after your context manager exits... This is of course not recommended because you're basically sticking your fingers where you shouldn't and possibly introducing hard-to-find bugs.

Other than that, I'm afraid it can't be done.

Comment: Hum... I'm not a big fan of having to use instantiate() to create objects... It will break a large part of the code base and would like to keep it as transparent as possible.

Thanks anyway, I'm gonna have a look to monkey_patching may looks like promising.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you can implement rather easily a slightly different context manager:

```
with my_context_watchdog(some_instance):
     pass
```

... but this is probably as good as a checker function and not the functionality you'd want. The magic of a context manager is __enter__ method, so there is just that much what can happen there, no any kind of massive overloads. There is probably a way to voerride __init__ method

You can also make some constructor that can differentiate the classes names and think of applying it to __new__  method too:

```
def new(cls):
     if cls.__name__ == 'BaseClass':
          pass
          # do something
     else:
          pass
          # do a different thing
```

Comment: I should have precised, I can't modify BaseClass nor SubClass. So impossible to modify __init__ and __new__. I will edit my post

Comment: you can achive some tracktion with standalone *new(cls)* function, but that would be a bit of wierd code, like ```obj_1 = new(BaseClass, name)```.

Comment: also a direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017397/injecting-function-call-after-init-with-decorator

Comment: That would definitely be a solution, however it&#39;s not intercepting the object creation, it&#39;s more encapsulating it.
Why would require to rewrite a large part of the code base and break code habits. I would highly prefer not doing it something like this

Comment: Oh that one is nice, I'll have a look. Thanks buddy!

Comment: It would be an interesting solution to intercept the object contruction indeed,  but it looks to be an interpreter-level hack. I doubt a context manger alone can help.